# Access-control-allow-origin is not present in Okta authorization URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, okta, openid-connect

I am developing rest services and consuming those by ajax.

Now I have secured my web service with okta and it is working well when I invoke from chrome or any browser. But If I tried to consume from Jquery/ajax, I am getting below error. Could anyone Please help on this.

I have used python, flask to develop web services and used OpenIdConnect(flask_oidc) for authentication.
 Piece of code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS"] = 
  services_dir+"okta/client_secrets.json"
app.config["OIDC_COOKIE_SECURE"] = False
app.config["OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE"] = "/oidc/callback"
app.config["OIDC_SCOPES"] = ["openid", "profile"]
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "********"
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/ai/*": {"origins": "*"}})


 @app.before_request
 def before_request():
     print("Before request",oidc.user_loggedin)
     if oidc.user_loggedin:
         #print("access token",oidc.get_access_token())
         print("sub",oidc.user_getinfo(["name"]))
         g.user = oidc.user_getfield("name")
     else:
         g.user = None  


@app.route('/ai/docsearchStatus', methods = ['GET'])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
@oidc.require_login
def getHealthstatus():
    response = {}
    response['user'] = g.user
    response=json.dumps(response); 
    return response
```

Jquery Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({     
        type:"GET",     
        url: "https://https://example.com/ai/docsearchStatus", 

        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success:function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){


        },     
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            //fnHideLoader();
            }               
    });
```

If I call https:///ai/docsearchStatus it is working properly(Redirecting--authenticating -- got response).
When I tried from ajax I am getting below URL:
    Error is :

```
  Failed to load https://mycompany.okta.com/oauth2/ausl2cu6foKJx4WXS0x7/v1/authorize? Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. Origin ‘https://example.com’ is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can any one help this. I have even configured https://example.com in okta admin through  API > Trusted Origins.

Comment: Access control headers have to be set by endpoint server in response. You can't set them in the client side request. You can use your server as a proxy to make the api request and call your server with the ajax and return the api data to the ajax

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have enabled cors in my services you can see in above code. if I remove  @oidc.require_login in above service it will work. Okta is not allowing.

Comment: So If I add origin as trusted in okta admin, It will resolve the problem. In that case I have already added.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a Trusted Origin in Okta.

In your Okta Admin Console, browse to: Security -> API and choose the Trusted Origin tab.

You can then define a trusted origin for CORS.

Full disclosure: I work for Okta.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have asked to my okta admin she confirmed that she has added trusted origin.

Comment: Even after adding the trusted origin, it's not working https://devforum.okta.com/t/cors-errors-even-when-using-trusted-origin/1486/2